# PHP Email Contact Form in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, contacts

I asked this yesterday, but I don't think I was clear...

I'm using a WordPress theme that has a simple PHP contact form that allows users to email each other. However, when one user sends an email to another, it's showing my WordPress admin email as who it's from and not the email address the user inputs in the email field when they fill out the form. (The form just consists of "Your Email" and "Your Message")

Here is a pic of the code:

[screenshot http://urbansheet.com/imgs/contact-sample.jpg](http://urbansheet.com/imgs/contact-sample.jpg)

- The **GREEN** area references the user's address who is receiving the email.
- The **RED** area references the title of the post the user is emailing about and shows up as the email Subject.
- The **PURPLE** area obviously references "Your Message".
- The **ORANGE** area displays in the body of the email and ".$email" does put the senders email address there.

But, like I said, I need emails to be "from" the sender's email address, not from my WordPress admin email. It serves no purpose if the receiver clicks Reply in their email account, they'll just be replying to my Admin address and not to the sender.

The way it is now, in order for the receiver to reply, they have to copy and paste the senders email out of the body of the email into a new email. Hardly convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the message as `from` the sender's email, you are more likely to be trapped in spam filters (since the sender's server doesn't *actually* originate the message... yours does).

Rather, set a `Reply-To:` header with the sender's email. Without seeing what you're doing in `send_email()` function, it's hard to know how you'd implement that. With PHP's `mail()`, it's easy.

```
<?php
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: sender@example2.com';

mail( 'recipient@example2.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers);
```

Just include the `Reply-To:` header along with the "sender's" email address when you invoke `send_email()`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So how would I reference the senders email? It isn't just one static email that it comes from. This is something they input. Would it be $email or "email" since the text field has the name="email"

Comment: Yes, best way would be `$_REQUEST['email']` if your input has `name="email"`. You can substitute `$_POST` or `$_GET` for `$_REQUEST` if you like (you'd need to determine whether the form is `<form action="post"` or `action="get"`)

Comment: Just saw you've already defined `$email` in your code from `$_POST['email']` so yes, go ahead and use `$email` as the reply-to :)

Comment: Okay, almost there. Haha.

Comment: This works      $headers = 'From: webmaster@mysite.com' . "\r\n" . '';
  $message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
  
  $p = get_post(get_the_ID());
  $a = $p->post_author;
  $a = get_userdata($a);
  
  mail($recipients = $a->user_email, __("", "ClassifiedTheme")."".get_the_title(), $message, $headers);

Comment: what the heck ... how do i post code again

Comment: the above works, but what do i replace webmaster@mysite.com with to get it to reference the sender's email

Comment: GOT IT!!! Ha. Thanks Set Sail Media you're a life saver.

Comment: Had to add this -- 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . ""; -- instead of an email address